# Changing Edit Summary of Edited Question

Tags: bug, editing

When reverting others edits to my question "[What are the signs of a watermelon past its best?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35806/signs-of-a-watermelon-past-its-best)", I was unable to change just the Edit Summary when I wanted to expand that summary subsequently.

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. Revert a post to an earlier revision, providing a Edit Summary
2. Revert post to same revision as Step 1, changing Edit Summary (This step can be repeated seemingly indefinitely to be step 3, 4, etc)

**Expected Result** - Edit Summary of Step 2 (or the last of Step 3,4,5,etc) would be displayed

**Actual Result** - Edit Summary of Step 1 displayed.

In case it is helpful for debugging this specific attempt (Not for debating the points of), I tried to change the Edit Summary the subsequent times to:

> Edit changed wording specifically chosen too vastly + Question isn't about food safety (https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+food), so tag addition and title editing are mutually exclusive + Don't want my question closed by the lack >of an explanation as to points of difference from previous question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9996/discussion-between-jefromi-and-user66001) (side discussion of whether the rollback was actually needed in the first place) I'm deleting the comments since they're archived in the chat.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this - I wasn't trying to say you had to use exactly the same format I did, just that you really didn't need to be using it as a vehicle for complaining about the handling of your original question.

Comment: I.m.o, very little of my original version of this question was addressing how I felt about the editing of the other question. It certainly wasn't meant to be a subtle, or otherwise, poke at how I felt about the editing of the other question. I guess I just put that in there for an background, which I agree was not entirely needed.